# Error running 'gradlew genIntellijRuns' command in IntelliJ for Minecraft mod development

Tags: intellij-idea, minecraft, gradlew

I am following a tutorial to develop a Minecraft mod using IntelliJ. When I try to run the 'gradlew genIntellijRuns' command in PowerShell, I get the error "gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized...". I have tried navigating to the root directory of my project and running the command again, but the error persists. I expected the command to download necessary resources for my mod development. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: here is  the error:
gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gradlew genIntellijRuns
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gradlew:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Suggestion [3,General]: The command gradlew was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\gradlew". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Comment: Try `./gradlew genIntellijRuns` instead.